# m3 instances have root EBS volume by default. so now what is the difference between m3 and m4?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

The AWS instances page indicates that the primary difference between the m3 and m4 instances is the EBS v/s instance-based (SSD) storage.

```
Instance Type   vCPU    Memory (GiB)    Storage (GB)    Networking Performance
m4.large        2       8               EBS Only        Moderate
m4.xlarge       4       16              EBS Only        High
m3.large        2       7.5             1 x 32 SSD      Moderate
m3.xlarge       4       15              2 x 40 SSD      High
```

But it looks like all instances are launched with EBS-based root volumes by default (https://stackoverflow.com/a/36688645/4040267), and I see this in my instances as well.

[m3 instance with EBS root volume](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLJli.png)

[m4 instance with EBS root volume](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZKqW.png)

In fact, the storage volumes for both the m3 and m4 instances look identical.

So what is the difference between m3 and m4 instances now, and what are the reasons for picking one over the other?

Comment: Later generation Intel CPUs is a key feature. Each generation is a small increase in performance on the last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

M4 instances are the latest generation of the General Purpose instances. M3 was the previous generation.

Amazon tends to make the new generation instances cheaper or raise the price for the old generation instances. My guess is to motivate customers to move to the new generation so that the old stuff can be decommissioned.

Which would you prefer: setup on newer hardware at a lower cost or select hardware that is a generation older and pay more?

Unless you have a pressing need to use the M3 generation due to compatibility reasons, etc., use the M4 generation.

[EC2 Instance Types](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/)

Comment: I don't recall AWS ever raising any prices in EC2.  They do, however, tend to offer better price/performace value in newer generations of instances.  One possible reason to choose m3 over m4 is that m3 supports both PV and HVM virtualization, while m4 is HVM only, which I suspect would be the "compatibility" mentioned here -- a PV AMI can't be launched on an m4 but will run on an m3 without modification.

Comment: Michael, good points.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, true, but not by much. Currently, m3.large is $0.133 per Hour while m4.large is $0.1 per Hour for on-demand instances. I don't see m3.* instances listed in the reserved instances pricing, so can't see the difference there. Does anybody know?

Comment: @Shankari $0.100 vs $0.133 is a substantial difference at scale, when you can get 40 machines for the price of 30, etc... and EBS-optimized (a separate network path to EBS for better peak EBS performance) is free with m4.  Also, the m3 is technically still "current generation" so prices are shown [here](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/reserved-instances/pricing/)... but note that m3 was never deployed in some newer regions, such as us-east-2... so if you don't see it, you are probably looking in a region where m3 isn't offered.  Also, unlike m3, the m4 has no ephemeral disks.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot with the update, my original question is answered. Thanks for the tip on why I wasn't able to see m3 instances on the reserved instances page.